# imponer bootstrap a estilo css

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

tengo una pagina que utiliza bootstrap y css. En bootstrap le asigno a un boton (login) del menu el color "success" y luego en el css le asigna a cada link del menu (en donde va incluido el boton) el colo negro. Entonces el boton me aparece de color negro cuando quiero que aparezca del color success. He probado a linkar el archivo bootstrap.min.css debajo del css que contiene el estilo pero sigue igual. Tambie prove a añadir `.nav li a:not(.btn){}` al css que maneja el background color del menu, pero sin resultado. ¿hay alguna forma de imponer el bootstrap al css?

```css
                        * {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            
            #header {
                margin:auto;
                width:500px;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            
            ul, ol {
                list-style:none;
            }
            
            .nav > li {
                float:left;
            }
            
            .nav li a {
                background-color:#000;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding:10px 12px;
                display:block;
            }
            
                        
                        
            .nav li a:hover {
                background-color:#434343;
            }
            
            .nav li ul {
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                min-width:140px;
            }
            
            .nav li:hover > ul {
                display:block;
            }
            
            .nav li ul li {
                position:relative;
            }
            
            .nav li ul li ul {
                right:-140px;
                top:0px;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

        
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div id="header" style='z-index:3;'>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Foro</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Armonicas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tecnicas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cuestiones Musicales</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>                                
                                    <li><a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Login</a></li>                              
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa la propiedad `:not` de CSS para que te imponga los estilos de tu selector excepto a las clases o selector avanzado que tu pongas dentro del `:not`, lo que pasa es que también el `hover` estaba afectando el estilo por eso no te funcionaba correctamente el `:not`, te dejo la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:not) para que le des un vistazo

```
.nav li a:not(.btn){
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
    display:block;
}

            
            
.nav li a:hover:not(.btn) {
    background-color:#434343;
}
```

```css
                 * {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            
            #header {
                margin:auto;
                width:500px;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            
            ul, ol {
                list-style:none;
            }
            
            .nav > li {
                float:left;
            }
            
            .nav li a:not(.btn){
                background-color:#000;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding:10px 12px;
                display:block;
            }

                        
                        
            .nav li a:hover:not(.btn) {
                background-color:#434343;
            }
            
            .nav li ul {
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                min-width:140px;
            }
            
            .nav li:hover > ul {
                display:block;
            }
            
            .nav li ul li {
                position:relative;
            }
            
            .nav li ul li ul {
                right:-140px;
                top:0px;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

        
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div id="header" style='z-index:3;'>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Foro</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Armonicas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tecnicas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cuestiones Musicales</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>                                
                                    <li><a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Login</a></li>                              
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: genial! gracias.